# Linear transformation with linearly independent subsets of domain and codomain

Tags: linear-algebra

If {$v_1, ... , v_k$} is a linearly independent subset of **R**$^{n}$ and {$w_1, ..., w_p$} is a linearly independent subset of **R**$^{m}$, is there always a linear mapping $T:$**R**$^{n} \to $**R**$^{m}$ such that {$v_1, ..., v_k$} is in Ker($T$) and {$w_1, ..., w_p$} is in Im($T$)?

As an optional second question: If it does exist, how could we construct a matrix for $T$?

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem says no.  But if you add the condition that $k+p\le n$, then yes.  The construction is fairly trivial.  Give it a try and see if you make headway.

Comment: Let $k+p≤n$. Define a linear transformation $T(v_i) = 0, i  = 1, 2, ..., k$, $T(v_{i+k}) = w_j, i = 1, 2, ..., n - k,    j = 1, ..., p$. Is this the construction you are alluding to?@Bye_World

Comment: Yep.  It just relies on 2 facts that hopefully you've proven in your linear algebra class: (1) one can always extend a linearly independent set to a basis and (2) a linear transformation (/matrix) is defined by its action on a basis of its domain.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there always a linear mapping $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ ?"

No, and to see that you can apply the rank-nullity theorem:

Let:
$$
B_v = \left\{ v1,\cdots, v_n \right\}\\
B_w = \left\{ w1,\cdots, w_n \right\}
$$

Where $B_v$ is basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B_w$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Assuming that $ker(T) = B_v$ and $im(T) = B_w$, we get:

$$
\dim \mathbb{R}^n = \dim (B_v) + \dim (B_n)\\
n = n + m \Rightarrow \text{ False!}
$$

With that you can conclude that the theorem says: No!

But if you get a injective map, you'll se that the kernel of that function is $ \left\{ 0 \right\}$, and then, by the theorem it's going to be possible... So it's possible, but not always!

To get the matrix of T, you'll need to apply the map $T$  to all the vectors that is in the basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then, the columns of that matrix of that linear transformation is going to be the transformed vectors of $B_v$.

The thing is to get why that matrix is going to be constructed like that... Think about spans and dimensions of domain and codomain... Try to understand what is happening and the matrix of transformation is going to be trivial to get!

Hint: Check this video to build up your intuition: "[Linear transformations and matrices | Essence of linear algebra, chapter 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=4)"

Oh, and 3Blue1Brown has just created a patreon account... If you like what he's doing to help students and math lovers all over the world, it's worth to contribute!

Thanks!